# Mozilla javascript How to get id of the bookmarks search side bar textbox

Tags: javascript, mozilla

I am working on an implentation in Mozilla javascript. 
I am finding difficulties getting id of the bookmarks search side bar textbox and display the content of it. [This](http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/components/places/content/bookmarksPanel.xul) is the link I am trying to follow.

Here is my code:

```
<hbox id="sidebar-search-container" align="center">
    <label id="sidebar-search-label"
           value="&search.label;" accesskey="&search.accesskey;" control="search-box"/>
    <textbox id="search-box" flex="1" type="search" class="compact"
             aria-controls="bookmarks-view"
             oncommand="searchBookmarks(this.value);"/>
  </hbox>
```

I am trying to fetch value using this code:

```
window.document.getElementById("search-box").value
```

Any help or suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the search textbox Id of the Bookmarks Sidebar with the followings.

```
var sidebar_text_box = window.sidebar.document.getElementById("search-box");
alert(sidebar_text_box.value);
```

Enjoy :)